# use google/wire with goland get undefined: InitializeEvent

Tags: dependency-injection, goland

i am learning google/wire with official tutorial, i can generate wire_gen.go file with wire command, but got erro :"undefined: InitializeEvent"   when i start build using goland.

Answer (score 1):

if exec commond "go build main.go", go don't build wire_gen.go file. so we should use commond "go build" or "go build main.go wire_gen.go", then go will build both main.go and wire_gen.go.

in goland we should change build configuration [image]